# There another way to add Azure Active Directory as authorization method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem that's I think it's important.
I'm trying to add Azure Active Directory authorization to my application.
And as every body knows it's using `ClientId`, and `TenantId` that's must be registered in `Startup.cs` file.
Here is my problem because I want to develop application that's use more than Azure Active Directory and store their information into Database and call a specified `ClientId` & `TenantId` from database and register them to my application in startup.
All depends on the sub-domain or normal user input.
So. How could I register Azure Active Directory information into `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` after application starts ??

Answer (score 1):

The method you are describing for supporting multiple Azure AD tenants is not very orthodox, and would be very onerous for all the parties involved to set up and maintain. Usually you would create ONE application, and mark it as multitenant - that would allow you to use your app with multiple organizations, without ever changing clientID or any other coordinate. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/ for an example.
if you are really set on your approach, one thing that might help is implementing the RedirectToIdentityProvider notification. Here you have an opportunity to modify the request message before it is sent to Azure AD, hence you could modify the parameters you want to change.